# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() with index function

Tags: python, arrays

Well, in my Python code I'm trying to print out the index of a list of lists using a list, this way:

`print(datos.tolist().index(lista_muestra_pequena[1]))`

'datos' and 'lista_muestra_pequena' are two lists of lists, and I want to know which index have `lista_muestra_pequena[1]` in 'datos'.
'datos' is actually a numpy array, that's why I put `.tolist()`

One error give me Python when executing, this one:
`print(datos.tolist().index(lista_muestra_pequena[1]))`

`ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

I understand the function 'a.all()', used for arrays to specify if all elements of the array must satisfy the condition, or only one in 'a.any()' case. However, I don't understand why is telling me this on this case. I tried putting 'np.all()' in two sites on the line, but I don't get it.

Comment: We don't have enough information, specifically on the contents and structure of your lists, to actually help out - a [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) would help a lot, since you can still show us the exact same issue but at the same time give us enough info to debug it ourselves.

Answer (score 0):

The `.index()` method will not work with an array as argument (assuming `lista_muestra_pequena` is an array).

For getting index of `datos` where `lista_muestra_pequena[1]` is, you can use [numpy.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method:

```
print(np.where(datos == lista_muestra_pequena[1])[0][0]) # first occurrence
```